# To print data to a text file except first column

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file links.txt:

```
1 a b c
3 b d
6 c j k l
```

I want to print data from links.txt to another text file except the first column.  Desired output in a text file:

```
a b c
b d
c j k l
```

Comment: Ask a ***question*** and ***show your code***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42323683.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims= " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %%b
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42323683.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Read each line of the file and tokenise into (first token, rest-of-line) using spaces as delimiters. `Echo` out just the `rest-of-line` part in `%%b`.

Enclosing the entire command in parentheses causes the output to be redirected to a new file.